# VBA - Conditional formatting: Excel 2010 won't work, Excel 2013 will

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2013

I recently wrote a piece of code that detects (but doesn't select) a `Range` which must be conditional formatted and then calls a subroutine that does the job.

```
' Format
For Each ws In Results.Sheets
    Format_em_all ws.Range(ws.Cells(15, 2), ws.Cells(15 + UBound(FreqToCompare), WrittenCells))
Next ws
```

Where `ws` is declared as `Worksheet`, `Results` as `Workbook`, `FreqToCompare` is an array with no possibility of being empty and `WrittenCells`is an Integer not = 0.

The Subroutine called:

```
Sub Format_em_all(RangeToFormat As Range)

    Select Case RangeToFormat.Parent.Name

    Case "lol"
        RangeToFormat.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, Formula1:="=2.9"
        RangeToFormat.FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        RangeToFormat.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=2.00001", Formula2:="=2.9"
        RangeToFormat.FormatConditions(2).Font.ColorIndex = 3

    Case "rofl"
        RangeToFormat.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlNotBetween, Formula1:="=-4", Formula2:="=4"
        RangeToFormat.FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3

    End Select

End Sub
```

I executed the code on my computer with Excel 2013 and all went smooth. 10 mins ago comes a colleague and says that my macro doesn't work... we go togheter to check on his computer with Excel 2010... and yeah, it doesn't work. It gets stuck at the first line after `Case "lol"` with a "Runtime error "5" - Invalid procedure call or argument".
I tried to `? RangeToFormat.Address` and it shows the correct range address... What is wrong with it?

Comment: what is the error you get? are the "magic numbers" what you expect (e.g. does xlCellValue=1) ?

Comment: Is there already a conditional format on this range?

Comment: What do you mean by "stuck"? Please clarify with a description of the error, or (if no error) a detailed explanation of how the observed results differ from your expectations.

Comment: Added the error description. Would Excel 2013 differ from Excel 2010 in the handling of a conditional format, should one already be there?
Actually no, the file is blank when opened and no conditional format is made before this Subroutine has been called.

Comment: I suspect the problem is not Excel 2010 vs. 2013 but the different decimal separators. The type of the Formulas is Variant. So try setting the Formulas to values not strings. Example: `RangeToFormat.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, Formula1:=2.9` and `RangeToFormat.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=2.00001, Formula2:=2.9`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the credit for this answer all goes to Axel Richter:

```
Sub Format_em_all(RangeToFormat As Range)

Select Case RangeToFormat.Parent.Name

Case "lol"
    RangeToFormat.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, Formula1:=2.9
    RangeToFormat.FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    RangeToFormat.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=2.00001, Formula2:=2.9
    RangeToFormat.FormatConditions(2).Font.ColorIndex = 3

Case "rofl"
    RangeToFormat.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlNotBetween, Formula1:=-4, Formula2:=4
    RangeToFormat.FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3

End Select

End Sub
```

As you can see, the formulas are not formulas anymore, but integers! That works flawlessly